# Prevent SCSS from compiling CSS variables - Angular-CLI

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using Angular5 with sass v1.3.2.

I want to be able to change a color that is used extensively in the scss files of my single page app in runtime (not by compiling new files).

The color is defined globally in my `_variables.css` as:

```
$brand: #123123;
```

And for example used as:

```
h1 {
    color: $brand;
}
```

I learned that I can modify the color if I am using CSS variables such as:

```
# CSS
:root {
    --brand: #123123
}

#JS
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--brand', '#456456');
# OR
document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--brand', '#456456');
```

However to be able to do that using SCSS, I needed to use [css-vars](https://github.com/malyw/css-vars) mixin as such:

```
$brand: #123123;

:root {
  @include css-vars((
    --brand: #{$brand},
  ));
}
```

And use it as:

```
h1 {
    color: var(--brand);
}
```

Two problems:

- Actually, still `--brand` is not showing at root.
- Also, the CSS generated in `<script type="text/css">` by angular-cli does not have `--brand` anywhere, it is actually compiling the CSS variable into `#123123` so the output is:

  h1 {
      color: #123123;
  }

Any ideas about how can I achieve changing a global color in runtime? Or how to get my CSS in `:root` and then how to get SASS to not compile it?

**UPDATE**

As @JonUleis has showed, there is no need for using `css-var`. Now the var `--brand` shows in the DOM at `:root`.

However, now `color: var(--brand);` line still does not show in the CSS, and `h1` doesn't have a color style at all.

After updating `node-sass` to the latest `4.9.0` from `4.8.3`, it worked great.

Comment: If you're still using `$brand` and not `var(--brand)` in the property values, why wouldn't it get compiled?

Comment: "However to be able to do that using SCSS, I needed to use css-vars mixin as such" - This is where you lose me. Why do you need to use css-vars?

Comment: @jhpratt I am expecting `$brand` in `:root` to be compiled, but I do not expect the output css to show `h1 { color: #123123 }` but actually to show `h1 { color: var(--brand); }`, but the problem is that it seems that SASS is compiling `var(--brand)` into `#123123` as if it is a SASS var.

Comment: @JonUleis because you cannot write `--brand: #123123;` in a SCSS file, it is invalid.

Comment: @zed Sounds like you may be using an out-of-date version of Sass. Works fine when experimenting on SassMesiter.

Comment: @JonUleis I just tried in SassMeister: `--brand: #123123;`, output is: `Invalid CSS after "--brand: #123123": expected "{", was ";"`

Comment: May I know why the question was downvoted while it is perfectly on the guidelines? Providing all the steps, versions, the question and output?

Comment: @zed Here's what I'm seeing: https://i.imgur.com/8ZXmhzE.png

Comment: @JonUleis updated

Comment: @JonUleis feel free to write your answer so that I can accept it as right answer.

Comment: @zed Done so - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely on an outdated version of node-sass that wasn't yet compatible with the syntax for CSS custom properties.

Here's your example code compiling successfully using Sassmeister without using the css-vars mixin:

[image]